# Is there any way to put dnn modules any where in the website to make a custom look?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to `DNN`, Can some body please tell me how can I put the modules any where?. I want to make website like this [link][1], but I am unable to put modules like in that website. `DNN` just allow to put modules in specific panes, but I want to put image slider in center as in the below website.
I have tried making `new skins, templates`, but I did not work. please someone tell me the exact solution. [1]: http://am.abudhabi.ae/PublicPortal/Home.aspx

Comment: @Mani, by your edition, you could also correct 'some body' .. ;)

Comment: how can i edit?? plz explain.

Comment: Under your question, on the left side, there are 'share | edit | close | flag  Try the 'edit' link.

Comment: what should i correct??

Comment: My comment was adressed to user Mani, saying 'while he/she edited your post could have by the same time correct the word somebody.

Comment: What you are asking for seem to be a basic functionality of DNN.  Worst case, you might need to change to a different skin.  Try this to learn more: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/videos

Answer (score 0):

This is something you do through the use of Skins and Modules in DotNetNuke

Answer (score 0):

when placing the module on the page select which panel you want it on, Ex. Content panel (center of page) Left Panel, Right panel Ect...